# Profile optimised C++/C code

Tags: c++, templates, stl, profiling, native

I have some heavily templated c++ code that I am working with. I can compile and profile with AMD tools and sleepy in debug mode. However without optimisation most of time spent concentrated in the templated code and STL. With optimised compilation, all the profile tools that I know produce garbage information. Does anybody know a good way to profile optimised native code

PS1:
The code that I am writing is also heavily templated. Most of the time spent in the unoptimised code will be optimized away. I am talking about 96-97% of the run time are spent in templated code without optimisation. This is going to corrupt the accuracy of the profiling. And yes I can change many templated code or at least what part of the templated code is introducing the most trouble and I can do better in those places.

Comment: If you're doing this on Linux, use gprof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should focus on the code you wrote because that is what you can change, time spent in STL is irrelevant, just ignore it and focus on the callers of that code. If too much time is spent in STL you probably can call some other STL primitive instead of the current one.

Profiling unoptimized code is less interesting, but you can still get some informations. If used algorithms from some parts of code are totally flawed it will show up even there. But you should be able to get useful informations from any good profiling tool in optimized code. What tools do you use exactly and why do you call their output garbage ?

Also it's usually easy enough to instrument your code by hand and find out exactly which parts are efficient and which are not. It's just a matter of calling timer functions (or reading cycle count of processor if possible) at well chosen points. I usually do that from unit tests to have reproducible results, but all depends of the specifics of your program.

Tools or instrumenting code are the easy part of optimization. The hard part is finding ways to get faster code where it's needed.

Comment: ++, especially for the first paragraph.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: Thanks for your comment. It is especially pleasing coming from you, as your answer to **Performance optimization strategies of last resort?** (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773) is one of my prefered answer ever on SO.

Comment: I meant it. I'm bemused when I see these call graphs showing layers of network in libraries where there's nothing you can do about it. I guess it's educational, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "garbage information"?

Profiling is only really meaningful on optimized builds, so tools are designed to work with them -- thus if you're getting meaningless results, it's probably due to the profiler not finding the right symbols, or needing to instrument the build.

In the case of Intel VTune, for example, I found I got impossible results from the sampler unless I explicitly told it where to find the PDBs for the executable I was tuning. In the instrumented version, I had to fiddle with the settings until it was reliably putting probes into the function calls.

Answer (score 1):

When @kriss says

> You should focus on the code you wrote
>   because that is what you can change

that's exactly what I was going to say.

I would add that in my opinion it is easier to do performance tuning first on code compiled without optimization, and then later turn on the optimizer, for the same reason. If something you can fix is costing excess time, it will cost proportionally excess time regardless of what the compiler does, and it's easier to find it in code that hasn't been scrambled.

I don't look for such code by measuring time. If the excess time is, say, 20%, then what I do is randomly pause it several times. As soon as I see something that can obviously be improved on 2 or more samples, then I've found it. [It's an oddball method, but it doesn't really miss anything.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) I do measure the overall time before and after to see how much I saved. This can be done multiple times until you can't find anything to fix. (BTW, if you're on Linux, [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/) is a more automated way to do this.)

Then you can turn on the optimizer and see how much it gives you, but when you see what changes you made, you can see there's really no way the compiler could have done it for you.